# Creating dummy variables in r statistical programming

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R Statistical Programming and I'm having some issues in creating dummy variables to recode a column of data. Below is a snippet of the dataset:

Year   Quarter   Sales     GNP
2002   1         696048    9740.5
2002   2         753211    9983.5
2002   3         746875    10048.0
2002   4         792622    10184.9
2003   1         704757    10206.2
2003   2         779011    10350.9
2003   3         756128    10332.2
2003   4         827829    10463.1

The three new columns I'm trying to create are d1, d2, and d3. 
d1 is a dummy variable that equals 1 if quarter 1 and 0 otherwise, d2 is a dummy variable that equals 1 if quarter 2 and 0 otherwise, and d3 is a dummy variable that equals 1 if quarter 3 and 0 otherwise.

I am using the below R code to try and accomplish this:

```
d1 <- ifelse(Quarter == 1, 1, 0)
Retail_Sales_vs_GNP <- data.frame(Retail_Sales_vs_GNP, d1)
d2 <- ifelse(Quarter == 2, 1, 0)
Retail_Sales_vs_GNP <- data.frame(Retail_Sales_vs_GNP, d2)
d3 <- ifelse(Quarter == 3, 1, 0)
Retail_Sales_vs_GNP <- data.frame(Retail_Sales_vs_GNP, d3)
```

However, when I review the new columns all of the values are equal to 0? d1 should equal to 1 if Quarter 1 but it equals 0. What part of my code needs to be revised to accomplish this?

Comment: can you show your expected

Comment: Sorry I can't post images for some reason. But the expected result is supposed to be like this: d1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 d2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 d3 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0

Comment: Based on your example and description, i posted a soulution.  Please check

Answer (score 0):

We can use `model.matrx`

```
df1[paste0('dummy_cols', 1:4)] <- model.matrix(~ factor(df1$Quarter)-1)
df1
# Year Quarter  Sales     GNP dummy_cols1 dummy_cols2 dummy_cols3 dummy_cols4
#1 2002       1 696048  9740.5           1           0           0           0
#2 2002       2 753211  9983.5           0           1           0           0
#3 2002       3 746875 10048.0           0           0           1           0
#4 2002       4 792622 10184.9           0           0           0           1
#5 2003       1 704757 10206.2           1           0           0           0
#6 2003       2 779011 10350.9           0           1           0           0
#7 2003       3 756128 10332.2           0           0           1           0
#8 2003       4 827829 10463.1           0           0           0           1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L), Quarter = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Sales = c(696048L, 
753211L, 746875L, 792622L, 704757L, 779011L, 756128L, 827829L
), GNP = c(9740.5, 9983.5, 10048, 10184.9, 10206.2, 10350.9, 
10332.2, 10463.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally when constructing linear models in R you don't have to construct the model matrix yourself.  Rather you can just specify Quarter to be a factor and `lm` will generate the model matrix for you.  Here are two ways to do it.  We have shown the model matrix so you can see what it looks like but other than that you probably do not need to explicitly generate it.

(The attribute part of the output below has been elided to keep the presentation shorter.)

```
# test data
Quarter <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4); Sales <- 1:8

Qtr <- factor(Quarter)
fm <- lm(Sales ~ Qtr + 0)

model.matrix(fm)
##   Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
## 1    1    0    0    0
## 2    1    0    0    0
## 3    0    1    0    0
## 4    0    1    0    0
## 5    0    0    1    0
## 6    0    0    1    0
## 7    0    0    0    1
## 8    0    0    0    1

Qtr <- relevel(factor(Quarter), 4)
fm2 <- lm(Sales ~ Qtr)
model.matrix(fm2)
##   (Intercept) Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3
## 1           1    1    0    0
## 2           1    1    0    0
## 3           1    0    1    0
## 4           1    0    1    0
## 5           1    0    0    1
## 6           1    0    0    1
## 7           1    0    0    0
## 8           1    0    0    0
```